# Show result count after while loop

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am trying to show the points outside whileloop. I am fetching result like this.

```
Facebook
Twitter,Facebook,Instagram,Youtube
Facebook
Facebook
```

It fetches Facebook from each row and count no of times in the end.

```
<?php 
  $q = "select * FROM users";
  $r = mysql_query($q);
  $total = mysql_num_rows($r);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $fb= $row['social'];
    $dbreq = implode(',',explode(',', $fb));
    $fa=array("Twitter,",",Instagram,","Youtube");
    $newstring = str_replace($fa, "", $dbreq);

    echo $points= count(explode(',', $newstring));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Why don't use select count(*)?

Comment: What is your question? What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to calculate no of times facebook saved in DB,either by direct or trimming the string

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_` functions are now no longer just discouraged (as it was over the last years), but officially [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). You should really use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), as this code will stop working very soon.

Comment: is this a comma delimited string? oh no!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this,

```
<?php 
$q = "select * FROM users";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$total = mysql_num_rows($r);
$cnt =0 ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
$fb= $row['social'];
if (strpos($fb,'facebook') !== false) {
   $cnt++;
}
}
echo "TOTAL:".$cnt;
    ?>
```

Comment: Where I echo the result?

Comment: I edited my anwser, please check, If it works please accept my answer